# How to share common lib's in ROS workspace

Tags: python, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having several packages in my workspace and I'm currently at the point where a want to avoid code duplicity. At the moment I have package called `myproject_common` in which all `msg` and `srv` files are located. After building the workspace they are properly available in all my other packages. Now I want to my common .py files into the common packages and also make them available. After calling `catkin_make` the `msg` and `srv` classes are available under `./devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` which is quiet nice because this makes them also available in my IDE without the need to import something manually. How can I accomplish this with self written common python files? What do I need to change in my `CMakeLists.txt` to get this working

**edit:**

I separated the `msg` / `srv` from the common modules, because the `msg` / `srv` stuff work fine so now my pkg with the shared modules is named `myproject_common_lib`

this is my directory structure

```
myproject_common_lib
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── package.xml
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── myproject_common_lib
        ├── coordinate.py
        ├── coordinate.pyc
        └── __init__.py

2 directories, 6 files
```

The content of my `__init__.py` looks like this

```
from coordinate import Coordinate
```

The content of my `setup.py`

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['myproject_common_lib'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

The content of my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(myproject_common_lib)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
)

catkin_python_setup()

catkin_package()

include_directories(
   $(catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS)
)
```

When I want to import the shared module I use the following import (which does not work)

```
from myproject_common_lib.coordinate import Coordinate
```

The content of my `devel` folder looks like this (short version)

```
devel
├── lib
│   └── python2.7
│       └── dist-packages
│           └── myproject_common_lib
│               ├── __init__.py
│               └── __init__.pyc
└── share
    ├── myproject_common_lib
    │   └── cmake
    │       ├── myproject_common_libConfig.cmake
    │       └── myproject_common_libConfig-version.cmake
```

I cannot see any difference to the posted tutorial. Also when watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bgrzZ45HMA) I cannot see any difference :-(

**edit 2:**

This is what PyCharm sees

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276307/how-to-share-common-lib%27s-in-ros-workspace/) by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2017-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to write Python modules (= libraries) and declare them, see [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile#Installing_scripts_and_exporting_modules).

So your modules will be available from your other packages and you will be able to import them using:

```
import myproject_common.my_module
```

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-11-20**:
When I follow the tutorial it works for the script but it does not work for my modules. The import cannot be found. The error I get is `Cannot find reference 'coordinate' in '__init__.py'`, which comes from PyCharm

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-20**:
Did you add an `__init__.py` file to the directory that contains your libraries/modules?

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-11-21**:
@jayess and @rreignier I updated my post with more information. Actually I cannot see any difference between my stuff and the provided tutorial

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-11-21**:
I found the error in the `CMakeLists.txt` the `$(catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS)` part must be written with `{}`